# How to run awk for some number of lines.?

Tags: linux, awk

I want to extract some lines with `awk`. Is it possible to do the following task:

```
ls -l | awk 'BEGIN FOR(i=122;i<=129;i++) FNR==i'
```

How can I display the details from line numbers 122 to 129?

Comment: If you were to do this in a loop, I'd suggest the `sed` method, since `sed` is so much smaller (and loads faster) than `awk`.

Answer (score 52):

You have not understood how `awk` works. The "program" specified is *always* executed once for each line (or "record" in awk parlance) of input, there's no need for `FOR` or any similar construct. Just use:

*verbose method*

```
ls -l | awk 'NR>=122 && NR<=129 { print }'
```

*more compact method*

```
ls -l | awk 'NR==122,NR==129'
```

Ths one give a range for `NR`, which is the "Number Record", typically this is the current line `awk` is processing.

Comment: Actually the typical `awk` code for such task is usually `ls -l | awk 'NR==122,NR==129'`.

Comment: what is the command for get last 100 line from the file using awk

Comment: @ShihabudheenKM May have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546919/awk-print-last-4-lines-of-the-file

Answer (score 11):

One more alternate method would be to use `sed`:

```
ls -l | sed -ne '122,129p'
```

But if, as your question suggests, it's important to use awk for this, go with manatwork's comment on Zrajm's answer.  As awk's documentation states:

> ```
>    A  pattern  may  consist  of two patterns separated by a comma; in this
>    case, the action is performed for all lines from an occurrence  of  the
>    first pattern though an occurrence of the second.
> ```

So if you want, you can also make more advanced conditions.  For example:

```
ls -l | awk 'NR==122,/foobar/'
```

This would start output at line 122, and continue until a line contained the word "foobar".

If you tell us the *actual* use case, we might be able to help with answers that provide a better solution.  I'm worried that this sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this (though I prefer the `awk` method) using coreutils:

```
ls -l | tail -n +122 | head -n 8
```