# Cut specific lines of file?

Tags: cut

I have a 100 line text file. I want to extract lines 50 to 70 inclusive. How can I do this? My Google skills are failing me and `man cut` doesn't seem to have the answer - perhaps I need a different tool.

Comment: `awk 'NR>=50 && NR<=70' file` have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89640/how-to-run-awk-for-some-number-of-lines

Comment: why don't you use head and tail combination ?